# ApplePay js - custom error message for completeShippingContactSelection

Tags: applepay, applepayjs

I'd like to add custom error message to ApplePay when shipping address is invalid. We have following code (that shows generic error message)

```
applePay.session.completeShippingContactSelection(
    ApplePaySession.STATUS_FAILURE,
    [],
    { label: "error", amount: "1" },
    [],
  );
```

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/applepaysession/1778008-completeshippingcontactselection), they introduced new error type on ApplePay version 3 (we use version 3). So I tried following code:

```
applePay.session.completeShippingContactSelection(
    {
      errors: [ { code: "shippingContactInvalid", contactField: "postalCode", message: "ZIP Code is invalid" }],
      newShippingMethods: [],
      newTotal: { label: "error", amount: "1", type: "pending" },
      newLineItems: [],
    }
  );
```

However I get an error at runtime - `TypeError type error`. Error is not displayed.

How can I display custom error message?

Answer (score 0):

Tips:

- `type: pending` hides total
- `label` should be a company name, like "Something LCC"

You can try to use ApplePayError constructor:

```
const zipAppleError = new ApplePayError("shippingContactInvalid", "postalCode", "ZIP Code is invalid");

applePay.session.completeShippingContactSelection({
  newShippingMethods: [],
  newTotal: { label: "error", amount: "1", type: "pending" },
  newLineItems: [],
  errors: [zipAppleError],
});
```